# Instance property 'Item(KeyValuePair`2)' is not defined for type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Object,System.Object]'

Tags: c#, automapper

I had the following mapping in my AutoMapper profile, and It was working:

```
CreateMap<KeyValuePair<int, string>, SelectListItem>()
    .ForMember(m => m.Selected, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(m => m.Text, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Value))
    .ForMember(m => m.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Key.ToString()));

CreateMap<KeyValuePair<short, string>, SelectListItem>()
    .ForMember(m => m.Selected, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(m => m.Text, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Value))
    .ForMember(m => m.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Key.ToString()));
```

After updating to Veriosn `5.1.1` I'm getting the following error in AutoMapper initializing:

```
Instance property 'Item(KeyValuePair`2)' is not defined for type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Object,System.Object]'
```

By commenting above mapping line I don't get error anymore but I need them.
How can I fix it?